# Error building libgfortran_6.2.bb recipe in morty: backtrace-supported.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, gfortran, yocto

I am trying to build the libgfortran_6.2.bb recipe in Morty.
I have included in my local.conf:

```
FORTRAN_forcevariable = ",fortran"
RUNTIMETARGET_append_pn-gcc-runtime = " libquadmath libgfortran"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gfortran gfortran-symlinks libgfortran libgfortran-dev"
```

But I get the error:

```
../../../../../../../../work-shared/gcc-linaro-6.3-r2017.02/git/libgfortran/runtime/backtrace.c:37:33: fatal error: backtrace-supported.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
Makefile:2419: recipe for target 'backtrace.lo' failed make[1]: *** [backtrace.lo] Error 1
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the fortran support in OE was broken for quite some time. This [patch series](https://www.mail-archive.com/openembedded-core@lists.openembedded.org/msg98442.html) brought in the needed fixes, but did not arrive before the rocko release development cycle. The series looks simple enough to be backported for your specific needs if desired, otherwise check if you can just forward your project to rocko.

Comment: I've got the same problem. I just updated to rocko, but seems like this is still busted :(

Comment: Hm. Do you specifically need v6.2, or just any libgfortran? I can try to reproduce and filter out the correct patches then.

Comment: Any libgfortran would probably be fine. It's pretty intimately tied into GCC though (it's part of the GCC distribution, which is at 7.2 as of Rocko), so it could be hard to replace in Yocto without also swapping out GCC/libgcc.

Comment: I think LetoThe2nd's comment is about the fact you're using gcc-linaro which ix 6.x based. If you use the default yocto 7.x in rocko, the fixes are likely simple to backport from master.